# How can I use web routes and api routes at the same time for Laravel 5.6 with jwt?

Tags: laravel, jwt

So in the documentation says (http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) to change defaults to api, like this:

```
'defaults' => [
'guard' => 'api',
'passwords' => 'users',
]
```

But then my web routes doesn't work.

Comment: Did you paste the code in `routes/api.php?` By default all api routes have the prefix **api/**. If you are pasting the routes code (as given in their docs) in `web.php`, they will obviously be overwritten. Can you share the code in both routes file?

Answer (score 0):

Literally apply the next set of instructions. 
You need to group your routes inside the API middleware.

So you'll need to do the same in your routes/web.php file. 
If you don't they will use the wrong middleware.

```
Route::group([

'middleware' => 'api',
'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});
```

http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/